# Adding quotes into a sql query with Vba code

Tags: sql, vba

I can recover data from my database using vba, but I have to add quotes on the result of column ("value1", "Value2", "Value3" etc)
But I do not know how to add quotes inside the SQL query, when using " it's wrong the request. 
I am used to do this kind of concat in SQL  but in VBA I am not able to do it.
Thanks for your help.

```vb
Sub CopyDataFromDB()
Dim DKCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim DKData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim iCols As Integer
Set DKCon = New ADODB.Connection
Set DKData = New ADODB.Recordset


DKCon.ConnectionString = SqlProvider
DKCon.Open

With DKData
        .ActiveConnection = DKCon
        .Source = "select sitsmhlccd from sitsmemoh"
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
End With

Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset DKData
DKData.Close
DKCon.Close
```

Comment: What SQL technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use VBA, you need to double double-quote if you want to use it inside a string:

```
"select '""'+ sitsmhlccd +'""' from sitsmemoh"
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it dosen't work. I have an ugly run-time error: Invalid column name '+sitsmhlccd +'

Comment: @YouFec: what is the back-end database?

Comment: @Louis: I am not concatenating strings, "+" symbol is inside of a string

Comment: @Louis: to concatenate double quotes with the result that's coming from the database, that's what OP is asking. The "+" sign will be part of the database query